# Cannot move forward when publishing Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, publish

I am using VS 2019 and web app is asp.net. I have signed into my Azure/Microsoft account through VS. When I tried to publish the app, I got the screenshot below. Somehow the "Next" button is greyed out so I cannot move forward to create my publish profile. By the way, I am learning Azure and using the free App Service Plan now.
[image]

Comment: looking at the screenshot, it seems like the Microsoft account you have signed into with VS is not associated with Azure. try this and use your Azure credentials when signing up : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2019

Comment: Rimaz, thanks. Very likely it is an Azure credential issue. The root cause could be either the Visual Studio or my Azure account. Still need to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create App Service：

[image]

see: [Publish your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnet-framework#publish-your-web-app-).

Comment: Carl, thanks for the screenshot, but could not even get to the screen. However, when I went through the publish process, I did see this screen in a split of second, then I got the screen where I could not move forward. So somehow Visual Studio does not think my Microsoft account has a valid subscription. I am contacting MS support. By the way, my Visual Studion 2019 is 16.8.2, which should be at the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happened. To associate with Azure, a Microsoft account is linked to an Azure Directory. When I sign into Visual Studio with the Microsoft Account, the link is supposed to established automatically. But somehow it was not for my case. In Visual Studio, open "Personalization Account" page, click "Apply Filter" link, the next scene is where I can select which directory to be linked. I had only one directory but somehow it was not checked. Once I checked it, I am able to publish.